# Stop autocompleting in markdown files in Atom

Tags: plugins, autocomplete, packages, atom-editor

I'm having trouble writing my markdown in Atom. As it is autocompleting from source files in the project. Note that I have https://atom.io/packages/language-markdown installed.

Is there a way to turn off autocomplete for a filetype? Or at least a file?

Answer (score 10):

You might try this blacklisting all the `.md` files from the autocomplete package.

Open **Settings** > **Packages** and find a package called *autocomplete-plus*. Go to its **Settings** and add `*.md` to the **File Blacklist** field.

Hopefully, you will not experience autocompletion in your Markdown files from now on.